# How to add BGM to my Android game

Tags: android

I've search alot but i couldn't find the full answer , anyway i've added a service to my game but now the problem is when i press the home/app list button the service ( BGM ) is still on , i've alot try to stop the service on (onPause function) in the main activity but my game use more then one activity , so when i start another activity the BGM is lost ( cuz it's calling MainActivity->onPause function )

so what i sohuld do ?

(my Serivce class)

```
package com.hema.mrlibya.firstgame;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

/**
 * Created by MrLibya on 18/04/17.
 */

public class BGMusic extends Service {
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bg);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
    /*
    public void onPause() {
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
        length=mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    public void onResume(){
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
        mMediaPlayer.start();

    }
    */
}
```

(Manifest)

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="BGMusic" />
```

(In the MainActivity i've only write on ( onCreate function )

```
startService(new Intent(this, BGMusic.class));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solotuion [here](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion)

it's work 100%

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: I suggest not to use  a service at all, since it is not necessary. Just instantiate the music player in the application. But that is up to your preference.

Secondly (your actual problem): When switching activies just set a flag e.g. `keepMusicOn = true;` and then

```
public void onPause() {
    if(!keepMusicOn){
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }
    //reset flag so that the music stops next time onPause is called
    keepMusicOn = false;
...
}
```

Comment: Thx i found the full one :)